# RxJava: How to dynamically emit items from an HTTP response

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2

I need to make a query to some external service, which returns a list of items. It needs to be done periodically.

This list of items needs to be the source for the RxJava computations.

So my question is:
How can I create an observable dynamically generates new items (i.e. using HTTP requests)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interval operator would do the trick:

```
Observable.interval(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .map { service.getList() }
```